# Android Webview using Jetpack Compose not respecting html and body 100% height

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having an issue with Jetpack Compose on Android 12 where I'm attempting to create a WebView whose contents fill the entire screen. For some reason even though the WebView itself seems to completely fill the screen according to the Layout Inspector in Android studio (for instance, it has a height of 811dp on a Pixel 5 emulator device running API 32), when I inspect the `html` and `body` elements in the actual HTML page in Chrome's inspector, they have a height of `0px` even though I have set them to `100%` height.  Rather than being presented with a completely green background like I would imagine should happen in a normal browser window, I am left with a blank white page, where the `div` in the `body` has a height of 0, the `body` has a height of 0, and the `html` container itself also has a height of 0.  When I query `window.innerHeight` in the Chrome JavaScript console though, I get a value of 811 which matches the height of the WebView in Android Studio's Layout Inspector. But when selecting the `body` element and querying `getBoundingClientRect()`, I get the following output:

```
bottom: 0
height: 0
left: 0
right: 393.0909118652344
top: 0
width: 393.0909118652344
x: 0
y: 0
```

Here is my sample code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            WebViewScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WebViewScreen() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                WebView(context)
            },
            update = { webView ->
                val HTMLstring = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }</style></head><body><div style='height: 100%; background-color: green;'></div></body><html>"
                val encodedHTML = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(HTMLstring.toByteArray())
                webView.loadData(encodedHTML, "text/html", "base64")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
        )
    }
}
```

Have I missed a modifier or something else that would define the height of the Webview inside the HTML document context itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the sizing as follows. I also changed the Base64 part to make it cleaner.

```
@Composable
fun WebViewScreen() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView(factory = {
            WebView(it).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
            }
        }, update = {
            val HTMLstring =
                "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }</style></head><body><div style='height: 100%; background-color: green;'></div></body><html>"
            it.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, HTMLstring, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! Is the `layoutParams` property something that is specific to Android `WebView` objects, or is that something that should be applied to any view type returned by a `AndroidView` factory function with JetPack Compose?

Comment: `Views` utilize `LayoutParams` to communicate with their parent elements about their preferred layout configuration. So it's not specific to `WebView.` For more info check it out: [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Comment: Just to clarify, a `LayoutParams` object is only required by a traditional `View` object returned by an `AndroidView` factory function to signify to its parent how it wants to be sized, correct? Additionally, a Jetpack Compose `@Composable` object should not need a `LayoutParams` object to determine its sizing, instead it can be sized using `Modifier` methods, correct?

Comment: Right, just use this method to display only XML-based Views in `Jetpack Compose` with `AndroidView`. However, for `Compose`, you should definitely use the `Compose modifier` anyway.